# Deployed my first Flask App to Cpanel, how can I access the live terminal view as I did locally?

Tags: python, flask, cpanel

I deployed my first flask app successfully onto Cpanel using the 'Run Python' option, this is working great.

However, I realize now, I am not able to see what the GETs and the POSTs are live, as I did when I was developing on my local machine.

Am I able to access this live terminal view, or is this something that is protected on the web hosts backend.

I can run a virtual environment, which technically I would be able to see this 'live terminal view' as I did locally, but, when I use the SSH terminal, I do not know how to bring up that instance of the application running in my browser, how would I bring that up, as it would also solve my problem.

I searched for this extensively on google and stack overflow, I did not see an answer.

For reference, I did not deploy this through Github. I manually uploaded the files to the webhost and run the python app inside Cpanel for the website, as it is my first web app and I wanted to learn how to do it the old fashioned way.

Thank you!